# Unchecked runtime.lastError: The color specification could not be parsed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I have error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The color specification could not be
>   parsed.

This indicates an error in the `popup.html: 1` ->`<! DOCTYPE html>`line. What is this about and how to remove it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app-container">
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you include a larger snippet of your code that the error message is referencing, as well as the full text of the error message, if there's more to it?

Comment: @thmsdnnr updated. It is full text. I added more code

Comment: The error message says you've passed an invalid color to some chrome.* API function. Probably to chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have: `chrome.browserAction.set BadgeBackgroundColor ({color: ' '});` to turn off the badge color

Comment: Use a transparent color e.g. `'#0000'`.

Comment: According to this comment on git (https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/270#issuecomment-463881161), try disabling all plugins on chrome (by going to chrome://extensions) and enabling them one-by-one to find the culprit. Which worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

According to this comment on [git](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/270#issuecomment-463881161), try disabling all plugins on chrome (by going to chrome://extensions) and enabling them one-by-one to find the culprit. Which worked for me!